# The three parts of the Wiccan Gods?

Tags: internal-consistency, religion

For one of my stories I intend to have a Wiccan character, and so would like to be accurate in my writing. In my research, I have come across the concept of the Goddess (for those that do not know, Wicca involves two main deities, the God and the Goddess) having three distinct forms or emanations, but different sources say different things about them, and I do not know what is true to the Wiccan system of belief.

Straight up [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicca) even implied that the God has three distinct versions as well, but I found no other source on it, but still do not want to ignore it if it is real.

What are the three parts of the Goddess, their names, and what are the parts of the God if such attributes exist?

Sorry in advance for my tags. I've always been bad with them, and I do not think that I've done them right.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really on topic here on Worldbuilding, you're asking about an actual real world religion... But from my experience with Wiccan friends and partners, there doesn't seem to be a hard established doctrine, more an amalgamation of bits and pieces from pagan religions.

Comment: Never heard of Wicca before but there doesn't seems to have another stack exchange appropriate to ask this.

Comment: @Vincent We're not a catch all site though - even if there's no other SE site appropriate to ask this on, it doesn't mean it's on topic here.

Comment: See the wiki wicca article.

Comment: I find that most of the questions I ask, such as this one, do not fall into a particular Exchange's sub categories. But this site has been the most helpful for me so far, though it still feels wrong of me to bother others with my irrelevant questions, and I apologize for that.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Mythology Stack Exchange is where you want to ask this. You're far more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: I was going to, but since Wicca is still being practiced, I felt it in poor taste to ask it on the "mythology" site.

Comment: I don't think this would be good for Mythology, not because it's about a mainstream religion (we do handle questions about stories from Judaism, Christianity, Islam, Hinduism, etc. there), but because it's not about a Wiccan mythological story. cc @adaliabooks

Comment: Adapting a real thing to your invented thing is Worldbuilding.  I vote to reopen.

Comment: @HDE226868 I suppose, but I assume there would be mythological stories that might answer the OPs question and explain the nature and origin of the Wiccan gods

Comment: @Will The asker is essentially asking "what are the details of my religion" which isn't world building - it's asking us to do their work. If he had already come up with those elements and instead asked about how to actually integrate those parts into his invented world, that would be on topic.

Comment: @Aify It would be difficult to "come up" with it, since it is a real religion that exists. It isn't "my religion"... where, then, would this be an appropriate question?

Comment: I asked about this on the [Mythology.SE Meta](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/405/170).  It would also be reasonable to ask on the Worldbuilding.SE Meta about whether it is/should be on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I urge you to **make it up**, in a way that is most useful for your story and which imparts the most narrative energy.

The whole deal with Wiccanism is a rejection of traditional authority and received wisdom.  People put together a thing that speaks to them and (maybe) their own group of like minded persons.  Some of these folks have the god and goddess, some of them have each with three facets.  Some just have the goddess.  Some have a neutral Deist sort of thing.  Many hybridize pseudohistorical things (for their gravitas) and invented / "rediscovered" new age things but I think a lot of people are fine with their own homebrew concepts standing on their own.

This really came home as I was reading up. There is no dogma.  The three aspects for the Goddess could be - young middle and old, like the Fates or Norns.  Wife, Mother, Grandmother.   The God piece seems even less fleshed out, with various options to choose from: Horned God (god of the hunt?), Sacrificial God who dies and returns alive (Green Man?  Mithra?  Jesus?  John Barleycorn?), Father, Sage etc.

If you want to have tripartite gods and you want some sort of canon as a creative guide, might I suggest you borrow from the Hindu pantheon and then adapt what you like to the neo-Celtic wiccan vibe.  For example Shiva: creator / preserver / destroyer and Kali: lover / mother / killer.  This will give the Wiccan thing a jolt of hybrid vigor unique to your story and let you sidestep criticism from persons who consider themselves authorities on wiccanism.

Plus the Hindu deities are awesome.

Comment: I suppose that I _could_ simply create a variant of Wicca, involving a triple God. What about this?

To The Maiden:  Kouros, The Youth, The Green Man - Birth, renewal, being "fresh into the world," naivety, and that childlike mind. Children start here.

To The Mother:  Kernunno, The Father, The Horned God - Virility, strength, endurance, and instincts. This is adulthood, the warrior and protecting spirit, and the main avatar of the God.

To The Crone:  Koios, The Patriarch, The Great Sage - Intelligence, wisdom, forethought, and tranquility. One should aim to reach this by their old age.

Comment: I buy it 100%.  Hybridizing the Celtic with the Greek is awesome as regards some sort of historic roots.  Plus Greek names appear all the time in English and will feel smoother than Hindu to a reader.  Great job!

Answer (score 2):

As you know, in Wicca, "the Goddess" is usually described as Maiden/Mother/Crone. The reason you can't find an equivalent three-part god for Wicca is because there isn't one.

While most major Wiccan traditions officially recognize the "masculine" aspects of divinity as equal to the "feminine" aspects; in practice, Wiccans place a stronger emphasis on the feminine. *This isn't without irony, considering the apparent misogyny of Wicca's founder.*

The lack of there being one generally accepted triple god isn't from a lack of trying, however. People have taken stabs at it over the years. Unfortunately for your purposes, most in the Wicca communities considered such efforts to be *forced*. (This is why I said there isn't "one", not "any".)

The most common variations of a tripple god I've heard of are Warrior/Father/Sage, Hunter/Father/Elder, Stag/Father/Sage (amongst Cernunnos fans), and Warrior/Father/Smith (thanks GoT). You could use one of those, a variant thereof, or something you made up entirely. It's up to you. Go with what's best for your story since Wicca doesn't have any strong preference on the matter.